# How to explain glitchy transitions after restart in Corona SDK program

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Below is a simple Lua program of a shelf moving left and right across the screen. When the screen is tapped, the shelf is supposed to reset and start at the left again. **But after that, the transitions.to do not work properly, as the shelf starts "jumping" back and forth.** Can someone please help me fix this issue?

```
local shelf

local function movingShelf() 
    shelf = display.newRect(56.5,250,85,10)  --display shelf

    local moveLeft --move shelf
    local function moveRight()     
        transition.to(shelf, {time = 5000, x = 261, onComplete = moveLeft})
    end
    moveLeft = function()      
        transition.to(shelf, {time = 5000, x = 57.5, onComplete = moveRight})
    end
    moveRight()
end

local function restart() -- restart the program
    shelf:removeSelf()
    movingShelf()
end

movingShelf()
Runtime:addEventListener("tap", restart) -- tap to restart
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transitions you initiate in `moveLeft()` and `moveRight()` are applied to `shelf` and you haven't cancelled them.  This can cause this kind of glitchy behavior.

To properly remove a DisplayObject, you need to cancel any transitions it is involved in.  In your `restart` function, you should do `transition.cancel( shelf )` before removing the DisplayObject with `shelf: removeSelf()`.  Finally, add `shelf=nil` for good measure (doing so is the recommended practice when removing DisplayObjects in Corona to avoid memory leaks).